# What PDL does the generic/text printer driver use?

Tags: printing

I have a Canon IR1023 printer that I'm trying to get working with the generic/text driver. I've tried every driver I can (UFRII, PCL, PS) but this printer will only print with the UFRII driver.

On Canon's specifications page it lists:

***PDL Support:***

`UFR II LT (Standard),
PCL 5e/6 (Optional with PCL Printer Kit-M1)`

I suspect I don't have the PCL Printer Kit-M1.

My question is, what PDL is it using when I select the Generic/Text driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **what PDL is it using when I select the Generic/Text driver?**

Essentially none.

---

If you regard ASCII control characters as a PDL then your answer is "[ASCII C0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_(ASCII_and_derivatives))".

ASCII includes the following control characters which, to some extent, arguably, **D**escribe some aspect of the **L**ayout of text on the **P**age in a rather primitive way:

- Carriage Return
- Line Feed
- Horizontal Tabulation
- Vertical Tabulation
- Form Feed

and probably others that don't immediately spring to mind.

Since Canon's UFR II appears to be a proprietary secret specification, 
there is no way to know if it will work at all with ASCII control characters.

Trying Generic/Text won't do any harm other than waste a little paper and ink. Tip: remove all but 5 sheets from the paper tray.

Unless your needs are very very basic (e.g. printing using a printer's default font such as Courier 10 from Notepad.exe and nothing else), it is unlikely to be useful.

Comment: Thanks, so is that what is considered `RAW` printing?

Comment: Raw printing usually refers to an application program bypassing the print-drivers of the operating system entirely (including bypassing any Generic/Text driver). The application itself effectively or implicitly does the job the drivers normally do for you. Personally I often use this approach to send Postscript directly to a printer. @Ryan.